# Update dictionary - the pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following piece of code which I believe can look more pythonic:

```
def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'extra' in kwargs:
        kwargs['extra'].update({'session_id': self.session_id})
    else:
        kwargs['extra'] = {'session_id': self.session_id}
```

I'm trying check if kwargs have a a dictionary named extra, if it does then add a value to it, otherwise create a new dict.

Comment: What about this isn't "pythonic" enough for you?

Comment: @ScottHunter for some reason it looks to me like a one liner and not 4 lines. Very java style, but, maybe you are right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly a bit more readable:

```
def info(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'extra' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['extra'] = dict()
    kwargs['extra']['session_id'] = self.session_id
```

Comment: Use `= {}` instead, because a function call has a bit more overhead.

Comment: More importantly, avoids redundancy.

Comment: Well I guess there is no right way, but this one is more readable, it makes sense and best of all it works also in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use dict [setdefault method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
kwargs.setdefault('extra', {}).update({'session_id': self.session_id})
```

If key is not present in kwargs it assing an empy dict to the key and returns it, so you can then update that dict.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a try except:

```
try:
    kwargs['extra'].update({'session_id': self.session_id})
except KeyError:
    kwargs['extra'] = {'session_id': self.session_id}
```

It's easier to ask forgiveness than ask for permission.

Answer (score 1):

most pythonic way is to use index. which is faster then update method of dict.

```
try:
    kwargs['extra']['session_id'] = self.session_id
except KeyError:
    kwargs['extra'] = {'session_id': self.session_id}
```

Comment: you should use index,rather than update method. update method is slower.